# Entity Framework Code First (with TPC) and Wcf Data Services Mapping

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, wcf-data-services

So, I have a TPC (Type per Concrete type) hierarchy as such:

**Order** and **OrderDetail** are both concrete types derived from abstract class **AuditableEntity**

The configuration for AuditableEntity is:

```
 public class AuditableEntityConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<AuditableEntity>
{
    public AuditableEntityConfig ()
    {
        //this.Property(m => m.IDN).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        this.HasKey(m => m.IDN);

        this.Property(m => m.Timestamp).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed).IsRowVersion().IsRequired();
        this.Property(m => m.AddedDate).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(m => m.ModifiedDate).IsOptional();
        this.Property(m => m.ModifiedByUser).IsOptional();
        this.Property(m => m.RowGuid).IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}
```

So the idea is to have this configuration for audit-related fields in the abstract class, and this would be applied to all derived classes. The following code is used while initializing the model:

```
var builder = new DbModelBuilder();
builder.Configurations.Add(new AuditableEntityConfig());
builder.Configurations.Add(new OrderConfig());
builder.Configurations.Add(new OrderDetailsConfig());
```

And the TPC settings are in the respective concrete type configurations:

```
Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Order");
        });

Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("OrderDetail");
        });
```

However, when this is accessed via a Wcf Data Service with a URL as *http:localhost:4040/MyService*, only the AuditableEntities type is exposed, and *http:localhost:4040/MyService/AuditableEntities* returns data for both concrete types, BUT *http:localhost:4040/MyService/Orders* or *http:localhost:4040/MyService/OrderDetails* does not work.

However, if I remove the "builder.Configurations.Add(new AuditableEntityConfig())", then the URIs for concrete types work and return data, but that defeats the purpose of applying the abstract configurations for audit-related properties.

The MyDbContext only exposes the Orders and OrderDetails DbSets:

```
public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
```

The Wcf Data Service is self-hosted in a WPF window. All permissions are given.

What settings am I missing?

SUPPLEMENTAL QUESTION: when i add this Service Reference to a client project, the context is named as 'CodeFirstContainer' instead of MyDbContext. Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? For the suplemental question I think the context is named after the first (and only in case of CodeFirst) entity container. Search for "CodeFirstContainer" in the $metadata output.

Comment: 'Does not work' means the browser displays 'The webpage cannot be found' error message. I checked the metadata, and the EntityContainer is indeed named CodeFirstContainer. Is there anyway to change this to the actual Service name?